How to place more than one variable on a single row using Flutter
I am using Flutter pdf package.
On a pdf document, I need to place several text elements on a single row.
Could you please advise how to do this. Thank You
pw.Center(child: pw.Text('Var 1: '+var1.toString(),style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight:pw.FontWeight.bold))),
pw.Center(child: pw.Text('Var 2: '+var2.toString(),style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight:pw.FontWeight.bold))),
pw.Center(child: pw.Text('Var 3: '+var3.toString(),style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight:pw.FontWeight.bold))),


i think you can use, pw.Row(children: [
pw.Center(child:...),
])

pw.Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    pw.Text(
      'Var 1: ' + var1.toString(),
      style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold),
    ),
    pw.Text(
      'Var 2: ' + var2.toString(),
      style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold),
    ),
    pw.Text(
      'Var 3: ' + var3.toString(),
      style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold),
    ),
  ],
),

